# Regex group include if condition

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

i have try to use that regex `/^(\S+)(?:\?$|$)/`

with `yolo` and `yolo?`

works with both but on the second string (`yolo?`) the `?` will be include on the capturing group `(\S+)`.

It's a bug of regex or i have made some mistake?

edit: i don't want that the '?' included on the capturing group. Sry for my bad english.

Comment: What are you ideally trying to achieve?

Comment: @AvinashRaj Sry for that next time i will explain better my problem

Comment: You're new to the site, so no problem :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You can use**

- If what you want to capture can't have a `?` in it, use a negated character class `[^...]` (see [demo here](http://regex101.com/r/uX7nL6)):

  ```
  ^([^\s?]+)\??$
  ```
- If what you want to capture can have `?` in it (for example, `yolo?yolo?` and you want 
  `yolo?yolo`), you need to make your quantifier `+` [lazy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301285/what-do-lazy-and-greedy-mean-in-the-context-of-regular-expressions) by adding `?` (see [demo here](http://regex101.com/r/xN0bY4)):

  ```
  ^(\S+?)\??$
  ```
- There is BTW no need for a capturing group here, you can use a [look ahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `(?=...)` instead and look at the whole match (see [demo here](http://regex101.com/r/tN2bP1)):

  ```
  ^[^\s?]+(?=\??$)
  ```

**What was happening**

The rules are: quantifiers (like `+`) are [greedy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301285/what-do-lazy-and-greedy-mean-in-the-context-of-regular-expressions) by default, and the regex engine will return the first match it finds.

Considers what this means here:

- `\S+` will first match everything in `yolo?`, then the engine will try to match `(?:\?$|$)`.
- `\?$` fails (we're already at the end of the string, so we now try to match an empty string and there's no `?` left), but `$` matches.

The regex has succesfully reached its end, the engine returns the match where `\S+` has matched all the string and everything is in the first capturing group.

To match what you want you have to make the quantifier lazy (`+?`), or prevent the character class (yeah, `\S` is a character class) from matching your ending delimiter `?` (with `[^\s?]` for example).

Comment: So i can't use + , any solution?

Comment: @Massimo1993: edited answer to add possible solutions on top of what was happening :)

Comment: Tnks a lot you have been very exhaustive

Answer (score 2):

The below regex would capture all the non space characters followed by an option `?`,

```
^([\S]+)\??$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/gN3hW9)

OR

```
^([\w]+)\??$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/yA3bW2)

If you use `\S+`, it matches even the `?` character also. So to seperate word and non word character you could use the above regex. It would capture only the word characters and matches the optional `?` which is follwed by one or more word characters.

Comment: The poster does not want `?` to be in the first capture group which it is with the regex he has provided.

Comment: @AvinashRaj look at your demo, it does what the OP doesn't want.

Comment: @MikeH-R Did you know what the op wants?

Comment: @AvinashRaj I think so (correct me if I'm wrong). He is trying to make a regex that will match `yolo` and `yolo?` but will have a capture group that only says `yolo` in it.

Comment: @MikeH-R see my second one.

Answer (score 2):

This is the correct response as `\S+` matches one or more non-whitespace characters greedily, of which `?` is one.

thus the question mark is matched in the `(\S+)` group and the non-capturing group resolves to `$` you could make it work as you expect by making the match non-greedy with:

```
/^(\S+?)(?:\?$|$)/
```

[demo](http://regex101.com/r/wS3vP9)

alternatively you could restrict the character group:

```
/^([^\s?]+)(?:\?$|$)/
```

[demo](http://regex101.com/r/vO3qQ2)

Comment: Sry doesn't work. Can't recognize the end of the string.

Answer (score 2):

Make the `+` non greedy:

```
^(\S+?)\??$
```

Answer (score 2):

It is doing that because `\S` matches any *non-white space character* and it is being **greedy**.

Following the `+` quantifier with `?` for a [**non-greedy**](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-greed.html) match will prevent this.

```
^(\S+?)\??$
```

Or use `\w` here which matches any word character.

```
^(\w+)\??$
```